# xslt to remove tags that names begin with specific name

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file that contains different tags and I want to get in output just tag that names begin with "C_"

How to do it with xslt
Thank you

Comment: Chceck XPath starts-with() function

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity transformation template plus a template that suppresses copying of elements that don't start with that name:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(starts-with(local-name(), 'C_'))]"/>
```

Comment: What if the root element doesn't start with "C_" ?

Comment: @StevenD.Majewski, if the root element's name does not start with `C_` then it won't be copied to the result. As the result of an XSLT transformation can be a fragment and does not have to be an XML document that is possible. Whether it is wanted by the poster I don't know, the question is short without any samples, the sole requirement "I want to get in output just tag that names begin with "C_"" is implemented by my suggestion. Let's wait whether the poster provides more details.

Comment: @Martin_Honnen : But it doesn't output tags that begin with "C_" if the root element and all of the parent tags don't also begin with "C_" . But yes, the main problem is that the question is ambiguous. But IF the root element does not start with "C_", then I think it unlikely that the OP wants no output.

Comment: Let's wait what the original posters says. It is not that difficult to change the approach to e.g. `<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(starts-with(local-name(), 'C_'))]"/>` if the rule should only be applied to leaf elements.